# How to change the domain for SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, domain

I am having my application on one domain and SQL server on different domain. How to link up them ?

Comment: Not programming-related - really belongs on Serverfault

Answer (score 1):

You could just use **SQL Server Authentication** instead of Integrated Security (Windows Authentication). Then you can Access your DB across domain boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

More complex solution is to establish trust between your domains using AD.

Answer (score 0):

At worst, you can use [NTLM Mirrored Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998292.aspx#paght000008_mirroredaccounts):

> Mirrored accounts are not recommended,
>   but are a workaround if you need to
>   use Windows authentication and your
>   Web server and database server are not
>   in the same or trusted domain or if
>   Windows authentication is blocked by a
>   firewall. To use mirrored accounts,
>   create a local account with the same
>   user name and password on each server
>   and then create a SQL Server login for
>   the local account on the database
>   server.

The link describes the process for ASP apps, but the same procedure applies to any application.

But the true, proper, solution is to establish trust between the two domains.